# Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

[image]

This error occurs while trying to add-migration for the first time. I have added the extension method and my service class

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

```
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers();
        
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(AppSettings);
        services.ConfigureJWT(Configuration);
        services.ConfigureIdentity();
        services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, CustomClaimPrincipalFactory>();
    }
```

public static void ConfigureIdentity(this IServiceCollection services)
{

```
        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(o =>
        {
            o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole),
       builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


    }
```

public class CustomClaimPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
{

```
    public CustomClaimPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ServiceSite", user.ServiceSite ?? ""));
        return identity;
    }
}
```

Here is the Error again

An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]': Unable to resolve service for type 'AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`5[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]': Unable to resolve service for type 'AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`5[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: AuthenticationService.Common.CustomClaimPrincipalFactory': Unable to resolve service for type 'AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[AuthenticationService.Entities.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,AuthenticationService.Data.AuthDBContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.)

Answer (score 31):

Register the dbcontext before you configure the Identity store

```
services.AddDbContext<AuthDBContext>();
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDBContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: what if you don't have a dbcontext? like when using dapper instead of entity framework?

Comment: I have same query as @symbiont

Comment: These will require some looking into as dapper is another use case all together. 
will share updates to this if I am able to make any meaningful progress on this.

Comment: If I change AddDefaultIdentity<1> to AddIdentity<1,2> then all the scaffolded identity pages (i.e. Account/Login) are just blank. Any Idea how this comes to be? Is scaffolding based on the content of program.cs?

Comment: in response to those asking about when using dapper, I had this issue when I added my custom dapper class as a constructor injection and forgot to register it in program.cs using AddTransient like so, builder.Services.AddTransient<YourDapperClass>() .  (Using .Net 8)

Comment: that saved me a lot of time, good point.

Answer (score 4):

For .NET Core 6.0

```
/*builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();*/
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 1):

in .net 7.0 and 6.0 just add the following

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
```

Answer (score 0):

add following line above builder.Services.AddIdentity

```
    var connectionString =                 
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionstring");
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<identitycontext>(options =>
    options.UseOracle(connectionString));
```